# unable to access metabase docker application on azure

Tags: docker, azure

I tried installing docker image on azure but I get error running my application.
I followed https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-quickstart and executed below command to create a metabase docker image.

`az container create --resource-group xxx --name metabase --image metabase/metabase --dns-name-label yyy --ports 80`

This command was successful but my application won’t load when I tried to access my application through `fqdn` given by the above command.

I can see the following in logs but I’m not sure how I can proceed and setup metabase.

```
05-08 12:28:18 INFO metabase.core :: Please use the following URL to setup your Metabase installation:

http://0.0.0.0:3000/setup/
```

Am I missing any step here?

Comment: DO you not need to specify an IP address somewhere?

Comment: @Burgi I'm new to docker and azure.. so not sure where I have to specify that ip address. I am following the link in my question to create a docker image for metabase.